# XLR Powered also an XLR output?

Tags: equipment

[image]I own a small 8-channel mixer(moon mc606beta) wich according to the manufacturer has an XLR output. But this is used to get power from an adaptor(below on it:"AC adaptor"). I'm wondering if the console can be used as a sort of DI/mixer using this XLR and getting power from the main board? 
I'm thinking this to connect my chapman stick to effects, then to the mixer, and go with 1 balanced out to the main desk.enter image description here

Thank you for your comments!

Lucas

Comment: Can you edit this to add in the exact model of 8-channel mixer you are asking about? Also, when you say "getting power from the table", what do you mean by "table"?

Comment: A word of warning. XLR male sockets are a good fit for 230vac 'figure of eight (Grundig) plugs. I found out with a new Roland keyboard, on a darkened stage. The repair bill is a little under £1,000...Phantom power is often available at XLRs, but it's something like 40vdc.

Comment: Tim thank you. I think the adaptor i use now is 18v( it reads 18+18 Vca on the adaptor provided by the shop). So theoretically i could connect it to the main desk using this output And getting power from it at the same time?

Comment: It would be very unusual, and unsafe, to have 'mains' power - even 18v+18vca going *into* an XLR socket on a mixer. There will most likely be 3 pins, but generally, the configuration will be different from a standard 3 pin XLR. XLRs are for signals, such as a mic in or line out.

Comment: Tim: I just added a picture. I never thought it could work as a XLR out until i read the description from the manufacturer. As you can see, the adaptor plug is female and the jack in the mixer is male. Thanks again

Comment: That looks like an Amphenol three pin male and female connector to me, and you could drive yourself nuts trying to get an XLR to fit it. Also the key slot won't line up.

Answer (score 2):

That connector is only for power. You won't be able to connect anything else to that besides the power supply for the Moon Mc 606. You can't use it as an audio output also.

If you look closely, you'll see it's actually slightly different from the XLR connectors that are used for audio signals.

Comment: yeah that is not XLR for audio.  also....don't lose that cable.

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning so much thanks to the kindness of strangers. Cheers.     I will look after the cable, yes!

Comment: The trouble with trying to replace anything like that is trying to figure out what the hell it's called. I have video lighting uses the 2-pin version of that plug/socket... can I find a source of spares for it if something broke... ... no. If anyone knows the name for that type of screw-in plug/socket, there would be gratitude in abundance :)

Comment: @tetsujin - Have a Google for "3 Pin Female Inline CB Mic Connector" - Looks very close, as far as I can tell from your photo.

Comment: ahaha... yes looks very similar - except a quick google shows that CB never uses 2 or 3-pin [which is probably for the best, as they're 18v...] but the general plug shape does look right.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Yamaha and Behringer use exactly that plug.

Comment: @tetsujin: I don't like putting links in comments, which is why I gave the search term I used, but... https://vetco.net/products/3-pin-female-inline-mic-connector

Answer (score 0):

That male connector is purely for ac in, but at 18vac. It's keyed, with a screw fixing, and although it looks like an XLR, the latter is slightly larger, and the male/female of each will not fit the other, thankfully. It actually says 'AC POWER **IN**', telling exactly what it's for!

'Getting power from the main board' isn't making sense. It will only get power from mains, with the correct adaptor, plugged in to that particular port.

It appears to be the same as some of the power-in ports on Behringer and Yamaha mixers, and the power supplies are available as spares including 18vac transformer.